# how to write a spark-transformed data back to a kafka broker using pyspark?

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

In my pyspark app, I intent to use Spark streaming as a method of transforming Kafka messages "in-flight". Each such message is initially received from a specific Kafka topic. Such message will need to undergo some transformations (let's says - substitute one string for another), and the transformed version needs to be posted on a different Kafka topic.
The first part (receiving a Kafka message) appears to be working fine:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

from operator import add
import sys
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
## Constants
APP_NAME = "PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount"
##OTHER FUNCTIONS/CLASSES

def main():
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    ...

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
if __name__ == "__main__":

   main()
```

What is the proper syntax to put something (let's say - a string) onto a different Kafka topic?
Should such method be provided by KafkaUtils, or is made available in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Within the handler function, we can do whatever with each record, and then send that record to a different kafka topic:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from operator import add
import sys
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json
from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

def handler(message):
    records = message.collect()
    for record in records:
        producer.send('spark.out', str(record))
        producer.flush()

def main():
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    kvs.foreachRDD(handler)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
if __name__ == "__main__":

   main()
```

To run this:

```
spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.1.jar s.py localhost:9092 test
```

Comment: Be aware, the connection should not be made on the driver then shared among the executors (which is a terrible idea, because a) it might not work and b) if it does it will add a serious overhead), but **created on each partition**. 

A couple relevant links

http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/

The Section "Design Patterns for using foreachRDD" on the Spark Streaming guide http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do according to SPARK documentation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd

```
def kafka_sender(messages):
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

    for message in messages:
        producer.send('alerts', bytes(message[0].encode('utf-8')))
        # For faster push
        # producer.flush()  

    producer.flush()



# On your Dstream
sentiment_data.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreachPartition(kafka_sender))
```